# Take values from list and assign to new property

Tags: c#, list

Lets say i got a list of strings like this:

```
List<string> cities = new List<string>();
    cities.Add("New York");
    cities.Add("Mumbai");
    cities.Add("Berlin");
    cities.Add("Istanbul");
```

I also have four strings like this:

```
string city1
string city2
string city3 
string city4
```

Is there a good way to somehow loop through the list and assign each var a city from the list? Im looking for a way to "pick-out" the values from a list and assign it to a new string.

```
foreach(var city in cities)
{
   string city1 = cities[0];, 
   string city2 = cities[1];
}
```

Maybe someone knows a much better way of accomplishing the same thing?
Thanks!

My real-world problem is this, here is my view:

```
<li style="left: 234px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 234px; overflow: hidden;" class=""> <img src="~/Content/img/slide-2.jpg" alt=""> </li>
                            <li style="left: 468px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 234px; overflow: hidden;" class=""> <img src="~/Content/img/slide-3.jpg" alt=""> </li>
                            <li style="left: 702px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 234px; overflow: hidden;" class=""> <img src="~/Content/img/slide-4.jpg" alt=""> </li>
                            <li style="right: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 234px; overflow: hidden;" class=""> <img src="~/Content/img/slide-5.jpg" alt=""> </li>
```

Since all the li-elements have different styles to the I cant loop through the list of hrefs the way i use to, I don not understand how to sove it without having my hrefs assigned to a singe var...Hope im clear enough...

Comment: Ok? I updated the loop in the question, is that correct?

Comment: If you want to do this dynamically then I would say you can't. That is why collections were made. If you want to do them statically then you can just assign each variable with the collections index e.g. cities[0]

Comment: I just did exact same loop as question, I can understand your reason behind it. what if you have 100 of cities do u add them one by one? But like @SpaceApple dynamically i dont think you can.

Comment: Ok I get it! I simply forget the loop and assign them "by hand". I did not know that I could access objects in lists simply by using the [index]. Thanks! Sorry to see all thedownvoting.

Comment: Why do you even have these 4 string variables? I can imagine whatever you are using them for, you don't need them

Comment: In my project the strings are hrefs for images that i want to use in my view, see update in question if you are interested.

Comment: @user2915962 - your 4 separate variables are just the elements of the array, so why not just access them directly from the array

Comment: You are right of course! That did not occur to me for some reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not do like suggested by "Grant Winney". Its simplest way until and unless you have fixed entries in list and fixed number of strings.

```
string city1 = cities[0];
string city2 = cities[1];
string city3 = cities[2];
string city4 = cities[3];
```

Comment: Im gonna mark this as an answer, its the same as @Grant Winney suggested in his comment. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :) , i already mentioned it in my answer as "Grant Winney" suggested.

Answer (score 1):

if you have to have them like separate fields, there is no much choice, if not like via reflection.

example:

```
 var fields = YOUR_TYPE.GetType().
     GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).
                  Where(f=>f.Name.StartsWith("city")).ToList();
```

and after:

```
 for(var i=0; i<cities.Count; i++) {
    fields[i].Set(....) //Set field value
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but...

As @Sayse commented, I also don't understand the reason of having those variables

```
string city1, city2, city3, city4;
```

If you don't plan to change `cityX`, then you can access original list values by using *index* in place where you had intention to use variables (`city1 == cities[1]`, `city2 == ..2`, `3 = 3`, you see?).

If your variables will be changed, but only to have *another value from the list*, then simply store *indexes* and change indexes.

Otherwise (if you plan to change values freely), organize them as array or list, to be something, what also operate with indexes. Then you can *save* on initialization, by using cycle (`for`, `while`, *linq*, etc.):

```
var city = new string[cities.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < cities.Count; i++)
    city[i] = cities[i];
```

instead of

```
string city1 = cities[0];
string city2 = cities[2];
...
string city112312315654654 = cities[112312315654654];
```

Comment: As you and @Sayse suggests is probably true in most cases, i was trying to "simplify" my question before posting in order to make it more broad. I updated my question where i also gave a brief description of my "real" problem. Thank you!